# DB2 Function with Object Reference as argument type

Tags: function, db2, object-reference

I have a pretty simple task but after hours of trying and research I couldn't find a solution. I want to create a DB2 function that takes an object reference as argument. I tried the following without success

```
Create Function FORMAT_ADDRESS(arg ref(Address_T))
    Returns Varchar(255)
    Return arg.username||'@'||arg."DOMAIN"
```

Create Type Statement:

```
create type address_t as (
username varchar(20),
domain varchar(20)
)
ref using integer
mode db2sql;
```

But I get this error, that username and domain are not known. I tried a lot of different things and ideas but it seems I just don't get the concept of db2 functions yet. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Might help to show the type definition DDL, as well as your DB2 platform and version...

Comment: Added the type definition.

Comment: Since you pass a reference to the `address_t` to the function, don't you need to dereference it within?

Comment: Hey, did you find the solution for it ? I tried it and i'm also stuck with db2 error, can you help me out if you have the answer?